# Seeding Tilecache with gdal2tiles output

Tags: gdal, tilecache, gdal2tiles

Very simple question. I've executed gdal2tiles against a GeoTIFF coverage, composed by several TIFF files. I want to serve the resulting tiles using TileCache.

In the TileCache [documentation](http://tilecache.org/docs/index.html), I see how to create new layers, using as sources JPG images, WMS layers, MapServer layers, etc (examples [here](http://tilecache.org/docs/EXAMPLES.html)). But the point is I want to directly provide the tiles generated by gdal2tiles as source. So, I want to access my tiles with something like:

http://example.com/yourdir/tilecache.cgi?LAYERS=basic&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&SRS=EPSG:4326&BBOX=-180,-90,0,90 &WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256

Or

http://example.com/yourdir/tilecache.cgi/1.0.0/basic/0/0/0.png

Using any TMS client. Now I'm using the Google Maps viewer generated by gdal2tiles, based on [GTileLayer](http://code.google.com/intl/es-ES/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference.html#GTileLayer)

Any tips on TileLayer configuration to achieve this goal are welcome. Or any suggestion to serve gdal2tiles output (tiles following the TMS spec) in a different way. I know, gdal2tiles was built following the TMS specs, before the WMTS standard. So, there're probably better ways to serve the gdal2tiles output today.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

" Or any suggestion to serve gdal2tiles output (tiles following the TMS spec) in a different way."

For what its worth, I put all of my tiles in Google's AppEngine datastore as "blobs" and serve them from there...

Example:  http://ericoneal.home.insightbb.com/LouisvilleMaps/

Comment: But, are those tiles generated by gdal2tiles? how do you reference them? do they follow a specific name convention in the datastore?